# For loop returns different results compared to While loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

Can someone explain why I'm getting incorrect results when I use a `for` loop?

**WORKING CODE:**

```
int smallest = myList.get(0);
int index = 0;
while (index < myList.size()) {
    if (myList.get(index) < smallest) {
        smallest = myList.get(index);
    }
    index++;
}
```

> 5 4 3 1 1 7
>
> Smallest number: 1 Found at index: 3 Found at index: 4

**INCORRECT CODE:**

```
int smallest = myList.get(0);
int index = 0;
for (index = 0; index < myList.get(index); index++) {
    if (myList.get(index) < smallest) {
        smallest = myList.get(index);
    }
}
```

> 5 4 3 1 1 7
>
> Smallest number: 3 Found at index: 2

Comment: What's the purpose the `index < myList.get(index);` comparison?

Comment: Your exit conditions are different.

Answer (score 3):

The limit of the `for` loop you have set was not right. Same like `while` loop it should iterate till the last element for getting the min value, for that we set its limit less than size of list.

```
for (index = 0; index < myList.size(); index++)
```

Comment: I got confused. Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (index = 0; index < myList.get(index); index++) {
```

As others have mentioned the problem is in this line specifically the `myList.get(index)` part. Instead of checking the size of myList it takes the current elements index as size. So for the first 3 you get lucky as `0 (index) < 5 (myList.get(index)`, `1 < 4` and `2 < 3`, but starting with the 4th element (index 3) you get `3 < 1`, which is obviously false and so the loop is stopped here.

Also just as a side note, if you don't use that first part of the for loop you can usually omit it:

```
for (; index < myList.size(); index++) {
```